# Defining an enum on ember DS.Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, enums, ember-data

I'm wondering what the best solution could be for using `ActiveRecord`'s [enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) alongside DS.model in Ember Data.

For example, if I have a enum in my Rails model:

```rb
# in the migration
t.integer :status, default: 0

# in the model
enum status: [:draft, :in_wizard, :published, :archived]
```

My first thought would be to define an integer type on DS.model:

```
status: DS.attr('number')
```

However, using Ember Data and ActiveModel Serializer, the serializer serializes these enums as strings, so json ends up with:

```
{status: 'draft'}
```

So should this be a `DS.attr('string')` or is there a way to specify an enumeration in ember data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use it as a string or you can convert it to a different type in the `Serializer`, however, it's probably easiest to leave it a string.  You can always add some computed properties to your model:

```
isDraft: Ember.computed.equal('status', 'draft'),
isInWizard: Ember.computed.equal('status', 'in_wizard'),
// etc...
```